# Uploading Video Error

Tags: 2013, library, video

When I try to add a video to video library (New Document>Video), after select the video, it gives me this error. What should I do?

> Working on it...
>
> This shouldn't take long.
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error Description:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

Comment: There is a lots of web.config file in LAYOUT folder. I couldn't find where the right one is. I don't want to make anything wrong. And I didn't understand why this error started to show up. Because I didn't edit any default code.

Comment: There is 2 web.config files. One of them in the <port of webapp>, and the other one in the <port of webapp>/wpresource. Which one is needed to modify?

Comment: It is Off. Here is some part of the web.config. <system.web>
    <httpHandlers />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/_login/default.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization> I alse add mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm" . But it didn't work also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11642/discussion-between-ruben-herman-and-e-ozmen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check your filesize when uploading large files. The default maximum upload size is 250MB, but can be changed in central administration (-> application management -> [your webapp] -> general settings -> maximum upload size)

For a powershell cmd:
http://sharepointrelated.com/2012/07/30/maximum-file-size-per-extension-in-sharepoint-2013/